# How can i redirect my laptop mic to gsm modem input..?

Tags: java, gsm, modem

I am using `atd<number>;` command to connect a call and I want to play a `.wav` file into the phone call.  I'm playing the audio file and connected my laptop audio out to microphone but it is not audible at the receivers end.. Please help me to solve this problem...
Are there any AT commands to redirect the mic to modem's input...

Answer (score 1):

It is not that easy. You see, the modem hardware in a laptop is not connected to the audio system in any way. So there is no physical way to route the output of the sound chip to the telephone line connected to the modem.

However, some modems support a `AT+VTX` command that allows you to send uncompressed, 8-bits sampled audio at 8 kHz. That should let you do what you want to achieve.

Wikipedia [explains the basics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_modem_command_set#Transmitting_audio_data) of this approach nicely.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.. is there any way to play the audio file

Comment: What do you mean by playing the audio file? If it is not clear, that AT command lets you send a wave file to the modem to play on the telephone line.

Comment: the command is for rs232 modems but my modem is usb connected to my pc. anyway i tried that one but it is not useful for me.

Comment: A USB modem just simulates how a classic RS-232 modem would work. It creates a virtual COM port for communication. That's why you could e.g. use the `ATD` command with your USB modem.

Comment: AT+VTX Command showing command is not supported.I tested this in telnet.Is there any alternative.? Please help me I'm stuck with this..

Comment: Are you using the right hardware? To playback voice through modem, you need a "voice modem". Most modems are voice modems unless they are very old or very cheap...
To learn more how to query the capabilities of your voice modem take a look at this page on wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_modem_command_set

Comment: I'm making the the call with the modems software with out any problem and the voice is also audible to other end..

Answer (score 0):

Hey Prakash I have found a work around for this ,when you record something to your pc using mic and save it in `.wav` or some other format and when played you can hear it in speakers what you recorded right !.So How can you hear that **?,** because this data is send as input to speakers right.**So From here what i did was ,I cut open one end of an aux cable and connected it Gsm Modems Input for Mic** it usually have **+ve**,**-ve** and **Ground** pins 
(My cable aux had RYW(color codes) *Here yellow is the ground*`*).`
Now Just Type The Following ATD   and play this `.wav` file you can hear that in the Phone you called .This is being tested successfully.
***What you have to do programmatically is to play this audio file upon call establishement***

### Cons

1.When you play another audio clip or if some system event sound occurs during call it will also be heard during call at receiver end

2.Cannot connect speaker at that point since its being used by this set up